# Fill slivers using R or SAGA GIS

Tags: r, slivers

I have  polygon shapefile representing administrative districts. There are small spaces between polygons where the polygons should be touching. There are probably also overlapping polygons. How can I have the polygons snap together, filling the gaps or slivers and removing overlap (possibly in R, QGIS or SAGA)?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this in R with the `rmapshaper` package, more specifically the `ms_simplify` function.

The best tool I've actually used for this is `pprepair`, which is a standalone C program, gettable from github:

https://github.com/tudelft3d/pprepair

Answer (score 0):

I'd use GRASS 7 for this personally, since its topologically aware. You can import with a snap distance set to remove small slivers, and then use the module `v.clean` in various ways to handle whatever other problems the software reports. As a last resort, you may have to hand edit a couple of points, but this should be unusual.